# Equations with few solutions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The only solution to the equation $x^2 + y^2$ over $\mathbb{F}_q^2$ when $q \equiv 3 \;(\bmod \;4)$ is when $x = y = 0$. Is there an analogous example in $\mathbb{F}_q^3$? That is, are there polynomial equations $f(x,y,z)$ whose only solution over $\mathbb{F}_q^3$ is when $x = y = z = 0$? For four variables, it is easy to produce an example, namely, $(x^2 + y^2)^2 + (z^2 + w^2)^2$, but I couldn't see how to proceed for three variables.

Comment: What about $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 0$? – That was before you changed the question significantly!

Comment: Whoops, should have spotted that! I've changed the field in the question from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{F}_q$, which I think makes the question harder.

Comment: Undoubtedly you are familiar with bounds on the degree of $f$ resulting from [Chevalley-Warning's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem) and [the Weil conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures) (proved by Deligne). The idea is that a lower bound for the number of solutions of a fixed polynomial equation is $>1$ for large enough $q$, ruining your day.

Comment: For example, with curves on the projective plane (= zeros of a single homogeneous polynomial in three variables) the Hasse-Weil lower bound for the (projectively inequivalent) solutions is $N\ge q+1-2g\sqrt{q}$.  Here $g$ is the genus of the curve. If the degree of the polynomial is $d$, then $g\le(d-1)(d-2)/2$, with singularities bringing this lower. Anyway, you should expect $d$ to increase (as a function of $q$) to get a lower bound that still allows the possibility that there are no non-trivial solutions.

Answer (score 3):

For $q$ a prime with $q>3$, consider $x^{q-1}+y^{q-1}+z^{q-1}=0$. As
$x^{p-1}=0$ or $1$, the LHS is either $0$, $1$, $2$ or $3$, and as these
are distinct modulo $q$, it's only zero when $x=y=z=0$.

Comment: Very nice, though I wonder if there's also an example with bounded degree?

Comment: A bounded degree is impossible. You need the degree to be at least $O(q^{1/4})$ to have a chance.

Comment: Why is this, given that the examples in my original question seem to generalise to give a polynomial of degree d in $\mathbb{F}_q^d$ when $d$ is a power of two?

Answer (score 1):

You've given the keyword *algebraic geometry*. The zero set of a (finite) system of equations forms a socalled variety and the system of equations forms an ideal in the underlying polynomial ring. The finite zero sets correspond one-to-one to the socalled zero-dimensional ideals. Zero-dimensional ideals have a nice characterization.

Comment: The point here is that the set of solutions of a single equation (a hypersurface) does not have zero dimension and yet intersects some subfield in very few points. I'm basically interested in what the nice examples of such behaviour are.